# How to fill in missing keys in an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of Objects which should all have the same keys, but some of the keys are missing. I would like to fill in the missing keys with a generic value.

I am looking for a simple way to do that (natively or via a library), the code below I use now works, bit looks to my untrained eyes quite heavy and I am sure I reinvented the tedious way to do something while there is a simple one.

```js
var arr = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 10,
    "c": 30
  },
  {
    "b": 200,
    "c": 300
  },
]
// get the list of all keys
var allkeys = []
arr.forEach((objInArr) => {
  allkeys = allkeys.concat(Object.keys(objInArr))
})
// check all arr entries for missing keys
arr.forEach((objInArr, i) => {
  allkeys.forEach((key) => {
    if (objInArr[key] === undefined) {
      // the generic value, in this case 0
      arr[i][key] = 0
    }
  })
})
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Note that there's a difference between a property that exists and has the value `undefined` and a property that doesn't exist at all. Your code is treating them as the same thing.

Comment: You really don't know the keys in advance?

Comment: Your approach in this case seems OK, but you might consider using a set instead of an array for `allkeys`. The value of `allkeys` in your code ends up being `[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "a",
  "c",
  "b",
  "c"
]`, but should really be `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: no, I get the data from an otherwise unhelpful API so I will have the case of non-existing keys only (not ones which have the value `undefined`)

Comment: @GolfWolf: thanks - I come from the Python world where I would have used exactlky that (a set), glad to see that there is the same in JS

Comment: @WoJ: Love those unhelpful APIs. :-)

Comment: @WoJ There is, but you need to check if it is supported on your platform. If it's not, just use the keys of an object as a set (as TJ Crowder shows in his answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a version using property spread in object literals, although this will have very limited browser support:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```js
var arr = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 10,
    "c": 30
  },
  {
    "b": 200,
    "c": 300
  },
]

// Create an object with all the keys in it
// This will return one object containing all keys the items
let obj = arr.reduce((res, item) => ({...res, ...item}));

// Get those keys as an array
let keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Create an object with all keys set to the default value (0)
let def = keys.reduce((result, key) => {
  result[key] = 0
  return result;
}, {});

// Use object destrucuring to replace all default values with the ones we have
let result = arr.map((item) => ({...def, ...item}));

// Log result
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I was unaware. I've updated my answer.

Comment: :-) It's also not object destructuring (which *was* in ES2015). It's "property spread syntax."

Comment: Just wanna point out that by now "all" browsers seem to support it, according to the MDN page (except IE of course). I'm not sure what the exact status was when you originally answered this question though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Object.assign* to merge each element with an object holding default key-values:

```js
var arr = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 10,
    "c": 30
  },
  {
    "b": 200,
    "c": 300
  },
];
var defaultObj = arr.reduce((m, o) => (Object.keys(o).forEach(key => m[key] = 0), m), {});
arr = arr.map(e => Object.assign({}, defaultObj, e));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That requires knowing the keys in advance. You might run an additional step that builds the `defaultObj` from the keys present in all the objects.

Comment: The OP doesn't know the keys in advance.

Comment: @Faly , can you suggest a solution where I wish to add the value as the previous record value for missing keys instead of setting all as 0?

Answer (score 2):

Your version is fine, although I would probably avoid all those array `concat` calls by just building up an object (or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) with the keys. It's also a bit less clunky with `for-of`:

```js
var arr = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 10,
    "c": 30
  },
  {
    "b": 200,
    "c": 300
  },
];
// Get all the keys
const keyObj = Object.create(null);
for (const entry of arr) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(entry)) {
    keyObj[key] = true;
  }
}
const allkeys = Object.keys(keyObj);
// Check all arr entries for missing keys
for (const entry of arr) {
  for (const key of allkeys) {
    if (entry[key] === undefined) { // ***I'd change this
      entry[key] = 0;
    }
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Re `*** I'd change this`: Note that there's a difference between a property that exists and has the value `undefined` and a property that doesn't exist at all. Your code is treating them as the same thing. Of course, if you know they won't have the value `undefined` (for instance, because of the API you're getting them from)...